# What command to generate BTC legacy address in electrum?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum

What command generates BTC legacy address in electrum?

here is a sample command:

createnewaddress()

Answer (score 3):

Command to create new address is same as you mentioned in the question:

```
createnewaddress()
```

You can only create `P2PKH` (legacy) addresses in a wallet with 'standard' seed:

Command to create a standard seed:

```
make_seed(seed_type="standard")
```

<sup>*'standard' can be replaced by 'segwit' for a wallet with bech32 addresses*</sup>

Create new wallet with the seed returned from above command:

File -> New -> Standard Wallet -> I already have a seed

Comment: File -> New -> Standard Wallet -> I already have a seed

is not working default is bech32 address cannot change to legacy or script address.

Comment: If you enter a "standard" seed you will see [standard](https://i.imgur.com/MtWJhn0.png) in seed type else if you enter "segwit" seed you will see [segwit](https://i.imgur.com/ts9fGS1.png) in seed type